# Can someone explain this? only one function in dart with void main?

Tags: javascript, dart

I feel like this is a really dumb question but It's hurting my noob brain.

Why in JS can I run multiple functions. But in dart I can use void main once and then cant simply run another functuion?

I know is probaly really simple but to a newbie these kind of things dont make any sense at all.

[image: Codebox Vanilla JS]

[image: DartPad]

Please see the pictures uploaded.

```
void main() {
  var value = "Dart is a worst version of JS";
  print('The value of the input is: $value');
}

void function() {
  var value = "Dart is a worst version of JS heres why";
  print('The value of the input is: $value');
}
```

(This code will only print Void mian to the console.)

Comment: In your JavaScript file you explicitly call `test` and `test2` - in your Dart file, `main` is [called automatically](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#the-main-function), but you never call `function` anywhere. If you want the code in `function` to run, you need to call it.

Comment: Notice how in dart, you are not actually _calling_ your functions anywhere, like you did in your plain JS version? That probably means that dart itself is calling a function `main` when it exists. And that likely also means, that you are _not supposed_ to have any functions besides this, that you would call yourself from that same context. Do what you need to do, _in_ `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really about running multiple functions, it's really about why does JavaScript allow executing arbitrary statements in the global scope (outside of functions), such as your calls to `test()` and `test2()`, whereas other (such as Dart) require that your program have some specially-named function (such as `main`).

The circular answer is because that's just how those languages were designed.  JavaScript, as its name implies, is intended to be a *scripting* language.  It's meant to usable with an interactive interpreter, where statements are evaluated as they're read.  Other languages with interactive interpreters behave the same way (e.g. Python, sh/bash/etc.).

That can be nice, but it has some drawbacks too.  It can hurt readability.  For example, if you have code like:

```
// Imagine that a few screenfuls of code goes here.

test();

// Imagine that a few screenfuls of code goes here.

test2();

// Imagine that a few screenfuls of code goes here.
```

then it's easy for the calls to `test()` and `test2()` to get lost.  It's not obvious to readers that they're called and when they're called.

If you evaluate statements outside of an explicit function, when exactly will they get called?  If you break up your code into multiple files that each might have such statements, what defines the execution order of those statements?  When you make one file depend on another, should adding that dependency introduce *side-effects*?  More concretely, should the act of importing one file from another automatically execute code in that file?  If multiple files import a single file, should code in that single file be executed multiple times?  What happens if there are circular imports?  What happens if one of those statements throws an exception?

A language designer could create answers for all of those questions, but it's often simpler to avoid them by requiring a single, well-defined [*entry point*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) to reduce ambiguity and confusion.  Dart generally prefers being explicit to implicit, so you must explicitly create a `main` entry point for Dart applications, where code will be executed in an explicit order.